# Connect to Google Cloud SQL from Macbook without firewall rules or allowed networks?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I leave this here in case someone else struggles with the same issue.

Visual representation of what I am trying to reach from my MacBook

MacBook -> VPN -> On-Prem Firewall -> GCP Firewall -> Cloud SQL Instance **NOT working** - detailed workaround below

GCE VM -> GCP Firewall -> Cloud SQL Instance **Working**

I had the issues where I could connect to Google Cloud SQL from GCE VM instance, but not from my MacBook, although I had firewall allow rules in place(which were correctly written).

I determined the problem was happening because I was on a work VPN that goes thru an On-Prem network that had is own firewall rules, so I had 2 firewalls to go thru, 1 On-prem and 1 GCP. I can edit the GCP Firewall rules, but am not allowed to do anything to the On-prem Firewall.

The workaround I found is the below:

Steps to be done in **Google Cloud GUI**

1. [Enable SQl Admin Api](https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=sqladmin) for the project your instance is part of
2. Give instance Public IP: Edit SQL instance > Connectivity > Public IP > Save
3. Don't authorize any external networks

Steps to be done **locally** on your MacBook

1. Install [gcloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-interactive) , dont forget about running **gcloud init**
2. Install a **mysql client**

   a.brew install mysql-client

   b.echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/bin:$PATH"' >> /Users/**YOUR_USERNAME_HERE**/.bash_profile
3. Download and install the [SQL proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy#install)(ignore the other steps 3,4,5 from the SQL Proxy article)
4. Disconnect from VPN
5. Run [step 4](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy#start-proxy) to start the SQL proxy
6. Connect to your instance from the mysql client(ex. mysql -u test_user --host 127.0.0.1 -p )

LE: The same approach can be done for windows users as well.
Any suggestions for optimization are welcome.